# What is the difference between full nodes, authoring nodes, and/or collator nodes

Tags: parachain, collator, nodes

What is the difference between the different types of nodes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Full nodes are nodes that just follow the chain. This means they are connected to the network and import all the blocks that are being produced.

Authoring nodes and collators are the same. Collators is just a different name to distinct authoring nodes from relay chain and the Parachain. These nodes are doing the same as full nodes plus they have block authoring running (and may a Grandpa voter).

Comment: So the only nodes that can author/produce blocks are collators?  Then the collator hands the newly authored block to a validator on the relay chain?

Comment: Yes exactly. The collators are building the blocks and send then to the relay chain validators.

Answer (score 7):

There are also Archive Nodes which are specifically full nodes but do not prune any historical state. This means they keep in storage all of the blockchain state for all blocks since genesis.